# Antimagic square induction problem

Tags: combinatorics, induction, magic-square

I'm currently trying to solve all the problems in Jay Cumming's book of proofs, and on the induction section, I'm having trouble solving a certain problem involving antimagic squares, the exercise is formulated as follows:
An antimagic square is an n by n matrix where each line, row and diagonal sums to a distinct value.
Prove that, for every integer n larger than or equal to 2, there exists an n by n antimagic square all of whose entries are positive integers.
My approach to solving this problem was a bottom-up approach, by trying to construct an n+1 by n+1 square starting from the n by n one, however, after some attempts, I still have no argument to guarantee that all the sums are distinct.
I'd appreciate any hints on how to solve the problem, perhaps faults within my approach or an entirely new one altogether. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you approached the problem?

Comment: @paw88789 Of course. I started by assuming an n by n square exists, then adding the n+1 line and row on top of it, empty for now. Suppose the largest element in the matrix is M, I set all the first n entries in the new row to M+1, leaving the last one empty, this assures that all the sums remain different. Now suppose the largest sum across the rows is L, so I added L on first n entries on the new line, this also assures the sums are different, and there are no repeats, the issue is with the diagonal that contains M and L, where I can't find an argument assuring it sums to a different value.

Comment: What do you mean by diagonal here? Only $\{a_{ii}\}_i$ and $\{a_{i,(n-i)}\}_i$, or any $\{a_{ij}:i+\epsilon j=c\},\epsilon=\pm 1,c=1,\ldots,n$?

Answer (score 2):

A non-inductive solution . . .

Fill the $n{\times}n$ matrix with $n^2$ distinct powers of $2$.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but do you have any approach involving induction?

Comment: @MHDFrags: I think it's unlikely that an inductive solution would be anywhere near as simple as the non-inductive solution I outlined.

Comment: I understand that, but the book I'm following asks for an inductive method to resolve the problems, it's a proof by induction section, so the point is to use to it to solve the problem. Thanks again though for your solution.